# Change URL in Browser Detection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, window.location

Hello I used UAParser as an identifier to detect what browser is used.

for example I have a window.location.href of "localhost:8000/"

when I reload and detect that it's from chrome it should change to "localhost:8000/#chrome

This is my code in doing it.

```
const [messenger, setMessenger] = useState(window.location.replace(`${window.location.href}/#chrome`))

let parser = new UAParser()
let browser = parser.getBrowser()
let browserName = browser.name

useEffect(() => {
 if (browserName.includes("Chrome")) {
   setMessenger(messenger)
   setOpen(true)
 }
}, [])
```

but what's happening to me is it's continuously refreshing the page and the result is localhost:8000/#chrome but keeps on refreshing.

sometimes what happens is localhost:8000/#chrome/#chrome/#chrome/#chrome

may I know what is missing or wrong in my implementation.

what I simply want is just add #chrome to be localhost:8000/#chrome

Comment: What's the value of `messenger` when you're trying to `setMessenger(messenger)`?

Comment: It just changes the url directly but it keeps on refreshing. and adding multiple /#chrome/#chrome/#chrome/#chrome

Answer (score 1):

Try to also check whether you already changed your location to stop refreshing:

```
if (browserName.includes("Chrome") && !location.href.includes("#chrome"))
```

Comment: when I tried this approach. my page refreshes twice.

Comment: @PinkyPromise Didn't you replace URL manually in the first line? Maybe this is the culprit.

Comment: yes, but I needed to change it if it detects chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `useState` for  (in your case `messenger`), just make it in the component constructor, ex:

```js
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false) // ? your default open value
  const parser = new UAParser()
  const browser = parser.getBrowser()
  const browserName = browser.name

  useEffect(() => {
   if (browserName.includes("Chrome")) {
     window.location.replace(`${window.location.href}/#chrome`)
     setOpen(true)
   }
  }, [])
}
```

Comment: hello but the result is becoming like this ..

`http://localhost:8000//#chrome/#chrome/#chrome/#chrome`

Comment: did you get rid of `[messenger, setMessenger]`?

Comment: Yes, this is my code now `useEffect(() => {
    if (browserName.includes("Chrome")) {
      window.location.replace(`${window.location.href}#chrome`)
      setOpen(true)
    }
  }, [])`